# node-gyp common.gypi 'uv_library%': 'static_library' syntax error

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7, npm-install, node-gyp

I was attempting to run npm install on one of my projects
however, I encountered an error in common.gypi regarding the Syntax of line 1
"'uv_library%': 'static_library',"

If anyone has any suggestions that'll be greatly appreciated! Using Mac, Node v18.18.0, NPM 9.8.1, Python 2.7.18 and 3.9.6

```
Error Message:
 File "/Users/MYNAME/.node-gyp/18.18.0/include/node/common.gypi", line 1
npm ERR!     'uv_library%': 'static_library',
npm ERR!                  ^
npm ERR! SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
```

Tried uninstalling Python2 (turns out it's needed, looked for a supported version), reinstalled Node + NPM, still seeing error message when running npm install, and also in the common.gypi file itself with various Python/pylance syntax errors

```
'uv_library%': 'static_library',

    'clang%': 0,
    'error_on_warn%': 'false',

    'openssl_product': '<(STATIC_LIB_PREFIX)openssl<(STATIC_LIB_SUFFIX)',
    'openssl_no_asm%': 0,

    # Don't use ICU data file (icudtl.dat) from V8, we use our own.
    'icu_use_data_file_flag%': 0,

    # Reset this number to 0 on major V8 upgrades.
    # Increment by one for each non-official patch applied to deps/v8.
    'v8_embedder_string': '-node.26',

    ##### V8 defaults for Node.js #####

    # Turn on SipHash f{
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Reverted back to Node V14.9 and ran npm with admin permissions then the errors went away

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `node-sass` has a problem in node v18 environment. Replacing `node-sass` with the `sass` package has eliminated the problem.

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```